# How to create a circuit that outputs only 1, regardless of inputs

Tags: binary, boolean, boolean-logic, circuit, circuit-diagram

So this is the truth table:

```
In_1  In_2  In_3  Out
0      0    0      1
0      0    1      1
0      1    0      1
0      1    1      1
1      0    0      1
1      0    1      1
1      1    0      1
1      1    1      1
```

How do I create a circuit that matches this truth table?

Here is what I have tried, but this did not work:
[image: attempt]

Please help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to connect the output to a constant logic `1`, which is usually just the power supply voltage. This is a trivial logic function and requires no gates to implement.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. so I just have to connect the inputs directly to the output?

Comment: No, you can completely ignore the inputs...you don't need to connect them to anything. The output is always the same, and is always 1, regardless of the input values. So, just connect the "output" signal to logic 1 (the power supply) and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to apply Kmap. We will be ending up with an equation that will be similar to

[image]

but this is not the reduced form. If we try to reduce this equation we will end up with 1.

Check this tool for better understanding.
https://www.boolean-algebra.com/kmap/